# Unable to save to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i'm developping an application with asp.net mvc code first approach and sql server 2008 .
my code is correct i don't have any error and the database is created by the entity framework , but when i try to add something , nothing is added !!
and when i try to debug the sql server it shows me this message :
the windows firewall on this machine is blocking remote debugging .
i clicked :
Unblock remote debugging from computers on the local network 
it showed me this message :
 "could not configure the windows firewall cannot add a port to the windows firewall exception list"
what should i do ? does this error Prevent my adding to the database

```
#region Create Projet 
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Projet());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Projet pro)
{
    objContext.Projets.Add(pro);
    try
    {
        objContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
        //EntityValidationErrors
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
#endregion
```

Comment: If the code was correct, you wouldn't have any problems. Nor should you require access to the remote machine - add *proper logging* and check the logs. Even bertter, add ELMAH and GLIMPSE to your application. Production sites never allow debug access - you can't stop an entire company just so you can debug a single page. Has an exception occured? What is the full exception text, including the call stack? Are you *sure* your exception handler didn't just hide a validation error? Why do you assume the error has anything to do with SQL Server?

Comment: PS: What you did, writing the error directly to the response is a *very* serious security breach, and probably superfluous. If you have an exception, you should care about the full exception text, not individual properties. Moreover, the text you write to the reponse may **never** reach the browser because you redirect to another page.

Comment: Check what data are you getting from the model ?

Comment: This is OS/Server configuration. Not on topic here.